# Asking for digital certificate

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic, digital-certificate

I think this has to be very easy, but I am a bit lost.

The issue is very simple, I have a web app that has to login using digital certificate. I have never managed digital certificates before, so I tried to copy the way other apps we have do it. In login controller:

```
    NegocioException.assertTrue(request.getAttribute(ConpactConstantes.ATRIBUTO_CERTIFICADO) != null, "Para acceder al sistema ha de indicarse el certificado digital.");
    X509Certificate[] certificados = (X509Certificate[]) request.getAttribute(ConpactConstantes.ATRIBUTO_CERTIFICADO);
    X509Certificate certificado = certificados[0];
```

when we I press the login button, I have NO window asking for the certificate, as the other apps do, and when doing: `request.getAttribute(ConpactConstantes.ATRIBUTO_CERTIFICADO)`I obtain null.

How can I trigger the window to select the certificate? Using weblogic 10.3.6

Answer (score 0):

The correct name of the attribute is `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate` (Servlet Specification 3.0 #3.8). It is indeed supplied as an `X509Certificate[]`. You have to configure your servlet or J2EE container to request or require the client certificate. If it isn't present it wasn't supplied.

Comment: yea, the constant `ConpactConstantes.ATRIBUTO_CERTIFICADO` value is that: `javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate`.

Comment: So have you done what I said in my final sentence? Correctly?

Comment: "You have to configure your servlet or J2EE container to request or require the client certificate"---> I think that's the point, I don't know how.

Comment: Well you need to investigate how to do that in Weblogic. I can't help you with that.